# How can I easily tell if my Excel 2007 code will work in earlier Excel versions?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2003

I recorded a macro in Excel 2007 which used TintAndShade and PatternTintAndShade. Unknown to me, [these two functions are not supported in earlier Excel versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773526/tintandshade-and-patterntintandshade-in-excel-2003) but [thanks to StackOverflow, I got a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773526/tintandshade-and-patterntintandshade-in-excel-2003/7773878#7773878).

Or so I thought. There are (apparently) other functions not supported by 2003. I say "apparently" because I do not have access to Excel 2003 but a colleague has told me that the macro does not work. I started asking him to tell me where the macro fails and then solving that (and iterating) but this is a slow process.

Is there an easier way? Is there e.g. a list of new commands in Excel 2007 or a simple compatibility check?

Comment: Have you tried opening a 2003 sheet in compatibility mode and run your macro? The non-compatible part of your code may fail which will help you find the issues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a coincidence, I came across this which might help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eric_carter/archive/2009/03/19/object-model-changes-for-developers-between-excel-2003-and-excel-2007.aspx

There is also a page on MSDN for Excel 2010 which although not directly relevant may also help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee836187.aspx

Comment: Now *this* is what I'm looking for! But why no mention of **TintAndShade**?

Answer (score 1):

No, not really and I doubt that there is a fully compiled list of object changes.

The best solution would be to develop in 2003, there are very few objects in 2003 that aren't in later versions - filesearch is the only one I can think of off the top of my head. However there are loads of things in '07 that aren't available in earlier versions, particularly notable are the new functions included in '07.

Do you really have no way of developing in '03 can't you install it? There isn't really a foolproof way of ensuring that your workbook will work correctly in earlier versions of Excel unless it was developed in an earlier version (or it's really simple)

Comment: Thx. No, I only have Excel 2007. Kind of weird, though, that I would need to develop in an old Excel version...

Comment: Other obvious difference is the ribbon which does not exist in 2003. Anything that creates custom ribbon in 2007 won't work in 2003.

Comment: Oh yeah, don't know how I missed that one ;) @Wikis, not really, in general it's good practice to work to the lowest spec of a users machine to make it as compatible as possible. - Though you can probably rule out anything less than 03